# expression must be a modifiable lvalue on struct pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct

i'm trying to fill the Item type "temp" with values that are in the array "temp 
fields" (Contains strings) i get the "expression must be a modifiable lvalue" error on my ptemp pointer.

```
typedef struct _item {
   char item_name[ITEM_NAME_LENGTH];
   char department[DEPARTMENT_NAME_LENGTH];
   char expiration_date[EXPIRATION_DATE_STRING_LENGTH];
   double price;
   int available;} Item;

Item create_item(char *s) {
    Item temp, *ptemp;
    ptemp = &temp;
    char temp_fields[5];
    int n = 0;
    n = seperate_fields(s, "_*_", temp_fields);
    ptemp->item_name = temp_fields[0];
```

can anyone explain whay this is happening? im trying to modify the value that the pointer is pointing at. that suppose to be modifiable

i thank anyone who answers in advance

the edited code for item creation

```
Item create_item(char *s) {
Item temp, *ptemp;
char *ptrend;
char *temp_fields[5];
int n = 0;
ptemp = &temp;
n = seperate_fields(s, "_*_", temp_fields);
strcpy(ptemp->item_name, temp_fields[0]);
strcpy(ptemp->department,temp_fields[1]);
strcpy(ptemp->expiration_date, temp_fields[2]);
ptemp->price = strtod(temp_fields[3], &ptrend);
ptemp->available = atoi(temp_fields[4]);
return temp;
```

Comment: `ptemp->item_name` is an array name. You can't assign it.

Comment: It seems this would be a good time to learn about the lack of accuracy for many values and calculations when using `float` and/or `double`  You might also want to learn about the `round()` function, found in math.h, as is `ceil()` and `floor()`

Comment: @user3629249 thanks!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're trying to copy a string, but you can't use `=` for that, because the destination is an array, and you can't just assign arrays in C.  Instead of this:

```
ptemp->item_name = temp_fields[0];
```

You can do this:

```
strncpy(ptemp->item_name, temp_fields, ITEM_NAME_LENGTH);
ptemp->item_name[ITEM_NAME_LENGTH - 1] = '\0';
```

Note I didn't use `temp_fields[0]` because that would be just one character, which doesn't really make sense.  Also note the explicit null termination after `strncpy()` because that function will not null terminate the output if there isn't enough space.

Comment: well i managed to fix this by only adding * to temp fields and using strcpy to copy the string. is there a problem with this method?

Comment: If you're asking me if your latest code is broken, you'll have to run it and see, or maybe edit it into your question.  I don't know what you mean by "only adding * to temp fields".

Comment: its returning a value that is 0.00000001 smaller

Comment: @Beginner: Floating point numbers are not exact.  A value  0.00000001  smaller than expected might be the best you can hope for using floats, depending on the magnitude of the actual value involved.  Read about IEEE floating point for more.